# How to debug with Emulator? Ionic App not opening in emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Please don't mark as duplicate. I tried all the options in the other posts that I came across.**
I'm trying to test my Ionic(3) Hybrid App in Android Studio Emulator using `ionic cordova emulate android --EmulatorName -l -c`. The built is successful and I get

> Package name: io.ionic.starter
>
> INSTALL SUCCESS
>
> LAUNCH SUCCESS

in the Visual Studio Code Terminal. The Emulator started s but however doesn't launch my app. The Emulator stops with the wallpaper screen.

I've tried most of the work around suggested here and in the common web. My environment details are as below:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\ilourdus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.16.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.16.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.5.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v6.11.4
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\ilourdus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro

Cordova Version:6.5.0
Android Version: 6.2.3
Android SDK Tools: 25.2.5
```

I used both `ionic cordova emulate amdroid --emulatorname -l -c` and `ionic cordova run android` and the results are same - Emulator starts but App doesn't load.

Please don't mark as duplicate. I tried all the options in the other posts that I came across. As said in some posts I checked the `adb command` in emulator.js. It has only `install -r` and no `-d`

Many have faced this situation. Anybody who had success with resolving this? or Is there a way to debug app in the Emulator? I tried `adb logcat` but the log size is more than 20K lines.

Any help here would be great. I'm struck here for 3 days now.

Comment: Is enabled the hardware acceleration for your emulator https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html?

Answer (score 0):

Try running these steps (in order):

- `ionic cordova prepare android`
- `ionic cordova build android`
- `ionic cordova emulate android`